# How to read an array into a view, in the Play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I read an array into a view?

```
@(week: Array[Int])
```

I've tried `@week[0]` but it's not working.

Thanks,
eapmartins

Comment: You can access specific elements by index by using `@week(0)`, aka `@week.apply(0)`. Though this is usually never recommended as it can throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` if the index doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in templates documentation (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaTemplates ), `Array` being `Iterable` you can do something like:

```scala
<ul>
@for(i <- week) {
    <li>@i</li>
}
</ul>
```